# Map of String to Method in Java 8, passing parameters

Tags: java, dictionary, methods, lambda, java-8

Ok, I have been trying to find an answer to this and I just can't wrap my head around the new java 8 lambdas and Method references.

I am writing an SVM decoder. I have the model, created by libSVM and can get all the relevant information like kernel type and constants like rho and gamma. I have a function that takes in a vector and classifies it using the kernel type of the model. Currently I just use a switch to figure out which kernel to use:

```
public double classify(FeatureVector v){
    double fx = 0.0;

    switch(kernel){
        case "linear":
            for(FeatureVector xi : supportVectors){
                fx += (xi.getWeight() * crossProduct(xi, v));
            }

            break;
        case "polynomial":
            for(FeatureVector xi : supportVectors){
                fx += (xi.getWeight() * polynomialKernel(xi, v));
            }

            break;
        case "rbf":
            for(FeatureVector xi : supportVectors){
                fx += (xi.getWeight() * rbfKernel(xi, v));
            }

            break;
        case "sigmoid":
            for(FeatureVector xi : supportVectors){
                fx += (xi.getWeight() * sigmoidKernel(xi, v));
            }

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return fx - rho;
}
```

Now, this works fine. But it is ugly and hard to follow. I have been reading up on lambdas and Method references in 8 and I just can't figure it out. Anyway, my ultimate idea was to have a map of strings (the kernel name) to the Methods for each kernel. And then to simplify the entire classify method to something along the lines of:

```
public double classify(FeatureVector v){
    double fx = 0.0;
    //get the method from map, this is where I need the help

    for(FeatureVector xi : supportVectors){
        //and how do I then pass params to the method?
        fx += (xi.getWeight() * kernelMethod(xi, v));
    }
    return fx - rho;
}
```

There is also probably a way with streams to then do the entire for-each loop but first I wanted to understand the lambdas and method references.

Comment: I think you dont need lambdas for that. You could use polymorphism or simple `switch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a map `Map<String, BiFunction<FeatureVector, FeatureVector, Double>> functions`, add your functions, e.g. `functions.put("linear", ThisClass::crossProduct)` and then do

```
BiFunction<FeatureVector, FeatureVector, Double> function = functions.get(...); 
fx += xi.getWeight() * function.apply(xi, v);
```

If crossProduct and co. aren't static, you'll need to do `this::crossProduct` instead.

Comment: Thanks! That makes some sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `lambda` just to use `lambda` ...

I would simlpy refactor your code like this :

```
for(FeatureVector xi : supportVectors)
{
    switch(kernel){
        case "linear":
            fx += (xi.getWeight() * crossProduct(xi, v));
            break;
        case "polynomial":
            fx += (xi.getWeight() * polynomialKernel(xi, v));
            break;
        case "rbf":
            fx += (xi.getWeight() * rbfKernel(xi, v));
            break;
        case "sigmoid":
            fx += (xi.getWeight() * sigmoidKernel(xi, v));
            break; 
    }
}
```

You might want to read about [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) to avoid this kind of switch statement which is most likely to become [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) over time.